# How to convert 0x80 in a 7-bit variable-length integer?

Tags: networking

Im reading a book about network protocol structures.

There is an illustration in a chapter about variable-length quantity, which I dont fully understand.(see attachment)

The subject is to convert different numbers to variable-length 7-bit integers.

The first line shows that 0x3F is stored in a single octet as 0x3F.

The second line shows that 0x80 is stored in two octets one as 0x80 and second as 0x01.

However I dont understand why its not 0x81 in the first octet and 0x00 in the second.

Because according to wikipedia, converting numbers into variable-length 7bit integers goes as follows:

1. Represent the value in binary notation (e.g. 137 as 10001001)
2. Break it up in groups of 7 bits starting from the lowest significant bit (e.g. 137 as 0000001 0001001). This is equivalent to representing the number in base 128.
3. Take the lowest 7 bits and that gives you the least significant byte (**0**000 1001). This byte comes last.
4. For all the other groups of 7 bits (in the example, this is 000 0001), set the MSB to 1 (which gives **1**000 0001 in our example). Thus 137 becomes **1**000 0001 **0**000 1001 where the bits in boldface are something we added. These added bits denote if there is another byte to follow or not. Thus, by definition, the very last byte of a variable length integer will have 0 as its MSB.

So lets do these steps for 0x80:

1. binary notation: 1000 0000
2. in groups of 7 bits starting from LSB:  0000001 0000000
3. and 4. set MSB as described: **1**000 0001 **0**000 0000

Converting that binary number into two hex octets, gives me 0x81 and 0x00.

Which leads me to the question: Is there a printing fail in the book or did I missunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which book is that?
There may be many possible encoding schemes. One of them could go like this:

```
   1. Represent the value in binary notation (e.g. 0x80 as 10000000)
   2. Break it up in groups of 7 bits starting from the lowest significant bit: 0000001 0000000
   3. Start with the lowest 7 bits: if this is *not* the last group of 7 bits, then set MSB: 10000000; if it's the last, then leave it
alone:    00000001
   4. Output starting LSB first: 10000000 00000001, i.e. 0x80 0x01
```

So what does the book say? What encoding scheme are they using?

Comment: Thats it, thank you very much for helping me. The book is called Attacking Network Protocols. There is no specific encoding scheme given in the book. However its obviously the scheme mentioned by you.